# Alternative to Centrifugo

Tags: software-development, websocket

A high performance websocket server that could handle a lot of connections

- if possible there's dotnet/Unity client, golang (or any server side language) client, javascript/Web client
- persist message if they disconnect then resend if they connected

Comment: https://go.libhunt.com/centrifugo-alternatives ?